# Reusing ActiveX Object throws a "write to protected memory" error

Tags: c#, activexobject

I have an ActiveX object that I am trying to close and then reopen, but it seems that something is lingering, and causing the error `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` The odd thing is that I have sample code for the object that works, and I call all of the same commands. My code is not identical, since the sample code just displays a test UI, but I have traced my code and the sample code as it ran, on two side-by-side computers. I'm at a loss.

I close the object like so:

```
        result = result && wrapper.Logout();            

        //  Throw the wrapper in the trash
        IsSelection = false;
        Controls.Remove(wrapper);
        wrapper.Dispose();
        wrapper = null;
```

When I recreate it, it claims that it is already initialized, but this happens in the test code as well. The error occurs when I try to log in again:

```
                result = wrapper.Login(Username, Password, Settings.AuthenticationSource, "", "");
                if (!result)
                    GetLastErrorCode();
```

The wrapper is just that; it wraps the actual communication code. Login looks like this:

```
return (bool)ocx.GetType().InvokeMember("Login", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ocx, new object[] { userName, password, authSource, token, mnemonic });
```

and Logout looks like this:

```
return (bool)ocx.GetType().InvokeMember("Logout", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ocx, null);
```

In my code, after recreating the ActiveX object, I can see values that I had added before destroying it. I know I am not doing something to finalize that destruction, but can't see what it might be. Is there anything obvious that I might be missing? If additional code would be helpful, please let me know what, and I'll try to post it.

Note that I do not have access to the code for the ActiveX object.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

EDIT:

The error text is as follows:

```
------ Exception ------
Error:  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Error:  Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
There was an error logging in to iSite.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
   at ...Login(String userName, String password, String authSource, String token, String mnemonic) in ...:line 375
   at ...Login() in ...:line 500
---- End Exception ----
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the code where the object is created:

```
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = 
        new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(xForm));
    try
    {
        wrapper = new xWrapper(Settings.ProgramID, Settings.ActiveXClassID);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { ... }

    //  Initialize the wrapper with default settings.
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wrapper)).BeginInit();
    ...
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wrapper)).EndInit();

    if (wrapper.SupportsPluginMessagingInterface())
    {
        wrapper.PluginMessage -= new xWrapper.
            _MessagingEvents_EventPluginMessageEventHandler(OnMessageReceived);
        wrapper.PluginMessage += new xWrapper.
            _MessagingEvents_EventPluginMessageEventHandler(OnMessageReceived);
    }

    GetLastErrorCode();
```

The wrapper constructor is just a default constructor, but later I do call initialize, which uses the following code:

```
return (bool)ocx.GetType().InvokeMember("Initialize", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ocx, null);
```

I added code to unsubscribe to the Event Handler, but this made no difference.

Comment: It looks like your ActiveX uses some static variables. Try this: `var ocx = wrapper.GetOcx(); wrapper.Dispose();  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ocx);`

Comment: @Noseratio - Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I came up with the same error. I've posted the error above in case it would be of use.

Comment: Could you show the code where you create the ActiveX object? Does it have any events that you handle?

Comment: @Noseratio - Thank you for your comments. I added the requested information to my question under EDIT 2.

Comment: Could you try it without handling `wrapper.PluginMessage` (or any other events) at all, but still with `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ocx)` at the end? Also, in the control's unmanaged API, is there anything like `Uninitialize` (you may check that with OleView).

Comment: @Noseratio - Thank you for the suggestion, but I had the same problem after removing all Event Handling. I checked the API, and there is no Uninitialize. The sample code that does work (that I all but copied) does not call anything special when closing.

Comment: I have one more suggestion. It appears this ActiveX doesn't have a UI. If so, instead of importing it with AxImp.exe or Visual Studio UI, try doing that with TlbImp.exe. You'll end up with raw interfaces, without any high-level .NET wrappers. Try using it that way.

Comment: @Noseratio - Actually, it does have a UI. I appreciate all of your help, and am thinking I will just leave it loaded in memory. Unfortunately, nothing worked, but I am giving you a plus 1 for all of your suggestions and help. Thank you.